# detect text input box value change

Tags: jquery, html, css

I looked for other answers but none seem to be working. I have an input of type text and when I change its value programmatically I want something to happen. However I can't find the right event handler to detect this.

[here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jq8abepn/)

heres some code so I can ask a question, all the code is on the fiddle

```
<input type='text'>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The change or other such kind of errors are not fired when you change the value of an input element programatically, so your solution will be is to fire the change event programatically once you change the value

```
$('#button').on('click', function() {
    value = $('#input').val();
    if (value == 'one')
    $('#input').val('two').change();
    else 
    $('#input').val('one').change();

});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/cp4andgp/)